# GridView, EDIT, UPDATE

Tags: c#, html, sql, gridview

I have created gridview with SQL db,  and i have created Three Textbox "CountryID", "Name", "CountryNotes",and add button in webpage, when i add details, it will added to the db and populated in the gridview.  i alo done coding for edit and update,  everything running perfectly,  but after i click update button details are updated to the grid view, but Textboxs not getting clear, update button Should Change to ADD button.

Here I am Adding My **HTMl Code :**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table align="Center" style="width: 50%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="CountryID" ForeColor="#CC0000"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name" ForeColor="#CC0000"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Text2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="CountryNotes" ForeColor="#CC0000"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Text3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" BackColor="#CC0000" ForeColor="White" ToolTip="Insert" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button2" Visible="false" runat="server" BackColor="#CC0000" ForeColor="White" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Cancel" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CountryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="Row_edit">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryID" HeaderText="CountryID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CountryID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryNotes" HeaderText="CountryNotes" SortExpression="CountryNotes" />
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Edit.png" CommandName="EditRow" />
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Delete.png" CommandName="DeleteRow" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>






            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATSConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Country1] WHERE [CountryID] = @original_CountryID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [CountryNotes] = @original_CountryNotes" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Country1] ([CountryID], [Name], [CountryNotes]) VALUES (@CountryID, @Name, @CountryNotes)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT CountryID, Name, CountryNotes FROM Country1" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Country1] SET [Name] = @Name, [CountryNotes] = @CountryNotes WHERE [CountryID] = @original_CountryID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [CountryNotes] = @original_CountryNotes">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryNotes" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CountryNotes" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CountryNotes" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryNotes" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Here I am Attaching **C# Code :**

```
public partial class Country : System.Web.UI.Page
{



    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }





    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button1.ToolTip == "Insert")
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RYI-SYS-004;Initial Catalog=ATS;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Country1 (CountryID,Name,CountryNotes) values(@CountryID, @Name, @CountryNotes)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", Text1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Text2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryNotes", Text3.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();


        }
        else if (Button1.ToolTip == "Update")
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["CountryID"]);
            update(id);

        }



    }



    protected void Row_edit(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
        {
            int nRowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            Int32 nCountryID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[nRowIndex].Value);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[nRowIndex];
            Text1.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
            Text2.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
            Text3.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            Button1.ToolTip = "Update";
            Button1.Text = "Update";
            Button2.Visible = true;
            int CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["CountryID"].ToString());
            ViewState["CountryId"] = CountryID.ToString();

        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
        {
            int id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            GridView1.DeleteRow(id);
        }

    }

    public void update(int id)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RYI-SYS-004;Initial Catalog=ATS;Integrated Security=True");
        int CountryId = id;
        string str = "update Country1 set Name='" + Text2.Text + "', CountryNotes='" + Text3.Text + "' where CountryID='" + Text1.Text + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Text2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryNotes", Text3.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = "Add";
        Button2.Visible = false;
        Text1.Text = "";
        Text2.Text = "";
        Text3.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: You might try using the `CommandName` property of the button rather than the `ToolTip`.  `CommandName` is the standard.

Answer (score 1):

**hi Dhivyadevi Dhanapal please ADD two things :**

1. create Method for clear and update grid view.

> ```
> public void clear()
>     {
>         Text1.Text = "";
>         Text2.Text = "";
>         Text3.Text = "";
>         GridView1.DataBind();
>     }
> ```

**2. call that method in Add Button.**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {

 if (Button1.ToolTip == "Insert")
        {

          //  con = your Connection String

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Country1 (CountryID,Name,CountryNotes) values(@CountryID, @Name, @CountryNotes)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", Text1.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Text2.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryNotes", Text3.Text);

            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

        }

        else if (Button1.ToolTip == "Update")

        {

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["CountryID"]);

            update(id);



        }


        clear();

    }
```

Comment: I think you mean "method", not "class".

Answer (score 0):

I would like to begin by saying that I see you are a new programmer. My first advice to you is that you should not just call textboxes and buttons textbox1 textbox2 and Button1 and Button2. This is the work of a novice. Call them meaningful names such as txtCountryID and txtCountryName in the TextBox ID area in the front end. Likewise Button1 should be called btnAdd and Button2 should be called btnCancel and you should then create backend functions for them separately. When you start designing your software correctly from the beginning you save yourself confusion and mistakes later on. Even if it is something as simple as calling the buttons and the textboxes meaningful names. It is all about thinking clearly and this is what it will help you to do.

Even your question is not clear but you are asking why are your textboxes not getting cleared when you have explicitly got code clearing them in Button2_Click. The simple answer is you are probably not pressing Button2 which is supposed to be the Cancel Button but which you have merely called Button2 which is not acceptable coding practice. Also changing button names is a shonky practice. Instead of changing button names, keep the button names the same and add more buttons for different operations.